# Json query vs SQL query using JSON in Oracle 12c (Performance)

Tags: sql, json, oracle, performance, oracle12c

I am using oracle 12c and Sql Developer with json

For this example I have the follow JSON:

```
   {
        "id": "12",
        "name": "zhelon"
   }
```

So I have created the follow table for this:

```
create table persons
id number primary key,
person clob,
constraint person check(person is JSON);
```

The idea is persist in person column the previous JSON and use a the follow query to get that data

```
SELECT p.person FROM persons p WHERE json_textvalue('$name', 'zhelon')
```

Talking about perfonce, I am intresting to extract some json field and add new a colum to the table to improve the response time (I don't know if that is possible)

```
create table persons
id number primary key,
name varchar(2000),
person clob,
constraint person check(person is JSON);
```

To do this:

```
SELECT p.person FROM persons p WHERE p.name = 'zhelon';
```

My question is:

What's the best way to make a query to get data? I want to reduce the response time.

Which query get the data faster ?

```
SELECT p.person FROM persons p WHERE json_textvalue('$name', 'zhelon')
```

or

```
SELECT p.person FROM persons p WHERE p.name = 'zhelon';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a virtual column like this:

```
ALTER TABLE persons ADD (NAME VARCHAR2(100) 
   GENERATED ALWAYS AS (JSON_VALUE(person, '$name' returning VARCHAR2)) VIRTUAL);
```

I don't know the correct syntax of `JSON_VALUE` but I think you get an idea.

If needed you can also define a index on such columns like any other column.

However, when you run `SELECT p.person FROM persons p WHERE p.name = 'zhelon';`
I don't know which value takes precedence, `p.person` from JSON or the column.

Better use a different name in order to be on the safe side:

```
ALTER TABLE persons ADD (NAME_VAL VARCHAR2(100) 
   GENERATED ALWAYS AS (JSON_VALUE(person, '$name' returning VARCHAR2)) VIRTUAL);

SELECT p.person FROM persons p WHERE p.NAME_VAL= 'zhelon';
```

Comment: If you create an index on column `NAME` the performance will be much better.

Comment: the index always improve the perfonamce, but for this case what happend if I index the clob collumn? @WernfriedDomscheit

Comment: Index on CLOB does not make any sense.